# AccessDeniedException How do i handle this error?

Tags: android

this is the error received in my android studio console after atempting to run/test an app on my usb connected android device

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\Android\sdk.android\build-cache.lock

I am unable to run my tests due to this error.
what do i do?

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by permissions of the operating system user on the directory.

These types of problems can happen because the folder the file is supposed to be written to does not exist, or because you are trying to write to a folder that requires admin access, but the user you are running the program as does not have that access.

Based on the filename `build-cache.lock` I am making the assumption that the build tool is trying to write to a lock file to make sure that only one build is going on at a time.

You should open up the directory in question `C:\Program Files\Android\sdk.android\` in a file explorer to make sure it exists.

If it does exist, check for the file `build-cache.lock` if it is there, try to delete it. otherwise check the folder permissions to make sure that you are allowed to write to that directory.

If the folder does not exist, then you probably need to re-install the android SDK.

Comment: what would i have to do. change directory? or install something. Thats where im confused.

Comment: +Thomas McLaughlin I have edited the post. Hopefully that should make the situation more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clone your repository back to a new local directory. Install the widget with the automatic alert (in case of VSC) and finish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I traced the path of the file at

> C:\Users\YourName.android\build-cache.lock

and discovered I did not have access. After I gave myself the permission to access the location, I tried building again and it worked.